# Probability someone never gets promoted?

Tags: probability, statistics, applications

I was doing some simulations on societal structures. For example, given a population, with a heirachy of N levels. e.g. one prime-minister, 10 cabinet members, 100 MPs, and so on. Let $P$ be the number of people that a person on a higher level has under their control. (In this case P=10).

And assuming that everyone starts their carreer on the bottom of the heirachy. And that everyone retires at a specified age. When someone retires, one person on the level below randomly gets promoted (and someone moves up to replace them and so on) and one new person starts at the bottom level. (We can assume some steady birth rate so the working population stays constant.)

Then I asked questions such as how long will the person at the top stay in power?

Let $L$ be the length of anyone's career before retirement. (e.g. 50 years).

I found that the average length of time the top person will stay in their job will be $L/N$ years.

In other words for a flatter heirachy the ruler will stay in basically half their life. Whereas for a tall heirachy the ruler will usually be very old by the time they get to the top and only stay there for a short time. (Think of the case where $N\approx 1$ and the case where $P\approx 1$).

In fact I compared this with the UK heirachical structure (I set $P=30$ and $N\approx 5.3$) and I get the length of time for a prime minister to be roughly the right 10 years. Which is kind of right.

But I also wanted to calculate the probability that someone in the lowest heirachichy will never get promoted and stay on the bottom rung all their life? Or to be more general the probability that someone will reach level $M$ before retirement.

Comment: How do you determine $L$?

Comment: We can assume someone works from 15 to 65. i.e. 50 years. But I'm leaving that as a variable in the model.

Comment: Yes, the rate of births would be $W/L$ people/year where $W$ is the total working-population and $L$ is working-length. For steady replacement I think.

Comment: I think I have found a way to estimate it.

If $W$ is the total-working population. Over a time of $L$ this means the entire population will be replaced so there will be $W$ promotions.

Let's say the proportion of people in the bottom level is $x$. You only get promoted if someone not in the bottom retires. So the probability of never being promoted is about $(1-(1-x)/W)^W$. For $x\approx 1-1/P$ and large $W$ this is about $e^{-1/P}$ if P is bigger than about 10. So if $P=30$, there is 97% chance you will never get promoted???

Comment: In fact because $e^{-1/P}\approx 1-1/P$. It says that the chance of ever in your whole carreer is about $1/P$. This sounds about right and I think this is probably the answer.

Comment: I don't understand what $(1-x)/W$ is supposed to represent.  $(1-x)$ is already a fraction.  What does dividing it by $W$ mean?  Also, $1/P$ is actually a _lower  bound_ for prob of promotion: You enter at the bottom at which point your boss is certainly older, so you will get at least $1$ shot for promotion (your boss retires before you).  The chance is $>1/P$ because (1) the new boss might still be older than you, so you get another shot, and (2) some higher-up retirements might cause chain reactions that promote your boss before your boss's natural retirement.

Comment: It is conceivable that $1/P$ is a reasonably tight lower bound, esp. for large $P$.  I wonder what the next term is.  E.g. is it $1/P + 1/P^2 + \dots$?  Or is it bigger at $1/P + 1/P\log P + \dots$?

Comment: @antkam. Well it also works when P=1. Since then the probability of promotion is 100% as a boss with only one staff member will certainly be replaced.  But yes, it must be more than that as you say your boss will be older than you. I didn't think of that. It's a harder question than it first looks! It might depend also on the number of levels too. I don't think my math is right since 97% of never being promoted seems wrong.